# I'm trying to create an html table with multidimensional array using php,

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

My array begins like this

```
Array
(
    [report] => Cost History
    [dimensions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [time] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [label] => Total
                                    [name] => total
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => 2018-11
                                    [label] => 2018-11
                                    [direct] => 
                                    [populated] => 1
                                    [excluded] => 
                                    [extended] => 
                                    [sort_order] => 
                                    [parent] => -1
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => 2018-12
                                    [label] => 2018-12
                                    [direct] => 
                                    [populated] => 1
                                    [excluded] => 
                                    [extended] => 
                                    [sort_order] => 
                                    [parent] => -1
                                )
```

[time] [0]->[13] creates the heading. I want the total column at the end.
Next I have

```
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Category] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [label] => Total
                                    [name] => total
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => sqs
                                    [label] => Simple Service
                                    [direct] => 
                                    [populated] => 
                                    [excluded] => 
                                    [extended] => 
                                    [sort_order] => 
                                    [parent] => -1
                                )
```

This is at the same level as time and needs to be my first column total at the bottom, there are [0]->[281] rows.
next I have the data.

```
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 59639.827459504
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0.4566711208
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 39.2084171093
                        )
```

This [data] is at the level of [dimensions] 
the first level of the array is for the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpMiQ.png)->[13] columns. and the second level is for the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpMiQ.png)->[281] rows. with the first row at the bottom with total and [data] second array total[0] at the end of each row. so $59639.82 at bottom right.

next I need to remove all the rows that total = 0 .

Here is what I started with it gives me the top row and first column.

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
$header        = $json['dimensions'][0]['time'];
$file = fopen('file/test.html', 'w');
$header1 = array();
$header1[0] = '<h2>Combined cost report ACR AMA</h2><table border="3">' . PHP_EOL . '<tr>' . PHP_EOL .  '<th>Services</th>' . PHP_EOL;
foreach($header as $item) {
  $header1[] = '<th>' .  $item['label'] . '</th>' . PHP_EOL;
}
$v = $header1[1];
unset($header1[1]);
$header1[] = $v;
$header1[] = '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
#$header1 = array_reverse($header1);
$header2 = implode("",$header1);
fwrite($file, $header2);
$service = array();
$service1 = array();
$services = $json['dimensions'][1]['Category'];
foreach($services as $item) {
  $service[] = '<tr>';
  $service[] = '<td>' . $item['label'] . '</td>';
  $service[] = '</tr>';
}
$v = $service[0];
unset($service[0]);
$service[] = $v;
$service = implode("",$service);
fwrite($file, $service);
$close = '</table>';
fwrite($file, $close);
fclose($file);
```

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpMiQ.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xflDz.png)

Comment: Whats the problem?

Comment: Having trouble trying to get the data array into the rows with category

Comment: Make a printscreen with the current result and draw one with the desired result.

Comment: Added images above

Comment: The what I have has 282 rows, the what I want is a partial

Comment: I was able to use shell_exec and bash commands to return the columns.

Comment: Shooting with cannons on pigeons